# how to solve the problem with this sweet alert?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert

I want to integrate sweetalert with my project. but I'm having the following error.

this is my html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.bank').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false,
            })

            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "Payment method Bank Transfer Mandiri!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
            reverseButtons: true
            },
            function(isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm){
                    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        $.ajax({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            },
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "{{ route('payment') }}",
                            data: $('#my-form').serialize(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                        //
                                }         
                        });
                    });
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've been looking for solutions to this problem quite a long time, but I still can not solve it

please help me. thx..

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: you have to put `error` and your `html` code also with question.

Comment: Provide aƒ [mcve]. Use the [live demo feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of the question editor. Include minimal HTML. Don't include a pile of Ajax stuff unless it is relavent. Link to CDN hosted instances of the libraries you depend on.

Comment: Without seeing the error you're getting, its very hard for us to help you.

Comment: onsubmit function doesn't working when the confirm button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Please include the CDN available for sweatalert.js .
As I don't see any erros above, 
I suggest you to add the following code before script .

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js
```

Comment: I already did that. onsubmit function doesn't working when the confirm button is pressed.

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuyết please check the console log inn your browser and tell us what is the issue or errors.